# PackageKit in suse Tumbleweed: disable or removal?

Tags: software-installation, opensuse

I have found that PackageKit is messing with the manual updates so to avoid this the process is killed.
But I whish to disable or removal this program (since I do all the updates manually), but will these options make a fault for the system?,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the **freedesktop.org** site:

> The actual nuts-and-bolts distro tool (dnf, apt, etc) is used by PackageKit using compiled and scripted helpers. PackageKit isn't meant to replace these tools, instead providing a common set of abstractions that can be used by standard GUI and text mode package managers.

I've personally never had issues blasting this out (in fact, I do it on almost every clean install of Fedora).  **However**, the sensible answer would be to use your system with it disabled for a while, and then uninstall completely once you're sure nothing breaks.

Link to more info on PackageKit: [link](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/PackageKit/pk-intro.html)

**EDIT:**

Found this in the FAQ as well:

> **Can users still use their normal package managers and backends, such as Yum, APT or Conary?**
>   *PackageKit does not stop you using the low level tools, in fact it quits as soon as possible if a native tool is waiting to be run.*

Comment: It is funny, perhaps Packagekit does not prevent directly the use of other tools such the mentioned ones, but at the moment that it is installing the RPM database went locked and no other installation program can access this so in the praxis, it does stop parallel use. But its a good answer and nice detail.

Comment: @riccs_0x I fully agree as I have experienced that same locking myself.  They really should bold the line "quits as soon as possible" in their documentation, as PackageKit's definition of "soon" and mine are not quite the same ;)

Comment: Well said =) Im holding for a couple of days, and if everything goes ok I will uninstall these thing.